# Why is the Kendo Mobile Switch not displaying custom labels?

Tags: javascript, jquery, telerik, kendo-mobile

It used to display the custom onLabel and offLabel text like this example from Telerik's documentation:

http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/mobile/ui/switch#configuration-onLabel

http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/mobile/ui/switch#configuration-offLabel

Now no custom text is being displayed.  My users are complaining.  Can this be fixed in the latest version of Kendo UI Mobile?

[image: Custom Labels No and Yes should be displayed]

**Unfortunately, the labels no longer show up:**

[image: No Labels]

﻿﻿Thanks,

Nathan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Official answer from Telerik / Progress was that the new Nova Theme does not support the onLabel or offLabel properties due to space limitation.

They are going to update the documentation.

Hopefully this helps the 2 other people in the world that switch from kendo ui mobile flat theme to the new Nova Theme. :-)